# Pyspark giving error with IN query in cassandra

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, pyspark

I have a large Cassandra keyspace (around 20 GB) on aws Cassandra server with a master server of 16GB ram. I am trying to run an IN query

```
"select colA colB colC where colA in {}".foramt( variable );
```

colA is Clustering Key.

variable is a python datatype which has around 500K entries. Currently I am facing two problems first is it is not at all working for above query and for variable of length around 20K it is taking around 20 minutes any optimization that can be done.

Comment: Read this : [Cassandra Query Patterns: Not using the “in” query for multiple partitions](https://lostechies.com/ryansvihla/2014/09/22/cassandra-query-patterns-not-using-the-in-query-for-multiple-partitions/)